# Asking about installation

Tags: 14.04

It is about installation. I bought a new laptop. Dos was already there but no other os.i tried to installing Ubuntu. It was installed and asked to restart now. It restarted and the dvd tray ejected. now when i start it  is showing the system is running on low graphic mode.  What to do now?!

Comment: DOS? Probably not.

Comment: @SurvivalMachine [FreeDOS is provided on some laptops for people who don't want to pay for a Windows license they're not going to use](https://www.google.com/search?q=freedos+windows+tax).